# FFTW 3 segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fftw

I am getting a weired segmentation fault while using FFTW with fortran and I've not been able to figure out why. No luck in online searches too. Here's my code:

```
 integer, parameter :: Nx=128, Ny=Nx, Nz=Nx
 integer, parameter :: NORM=Nx*Ny*Nz,Ntop=MAX(Nx,Ny,Nz)/2, LX1=Nx/2+1
 double precision, parameter :: Etot=0.5
 double complex, dimension(LX1,Ny,Nz) :: fbx, fby, fbz
 double precision, dimension(Nx,Ny,Nz) :: bx, by, bz
 real
 ! ...
 ! Assign values to fbx, fby, fbz 
 ! ...
 call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_3d(plan,Nx,Ny,Nz,fbx,bx,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
 call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan, fbx, bx)
 call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan, fby, by)
 call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan, fbz, bz)
 call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan)
 ! et = sum(abs(fbx)**2+abs(fby)**2+abs(fbz)**2)
 ! bx=bx*sqrt(Etot/et); by=by*sqrt(Etot/et); bz=bz*sqrt(Etot/et)

 ! Write bx, by, bz to files
```

The code runs fine this way. The problem arises when I uncomment the lines computing et and rescaling bx. When I uncomment those lines, I get segmentation fault saying "invalid memory reference". The seg fault occurs at the first execution of dfftw_execute_dft_c2r()

I've tried both fftw 3.2 and fftw 3.4 with ifort as well as gfortran on two different machines (with every possible combination of these) without any success.

It's driving me crazy!! I need help please!! Why is it happening this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you cimoile with error checking? Did you try a debugger?

Comment: I did compile with error checking and the debugger tells me only where the fault is (as I mention in my original post).

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same plan applied to different arrays. FFTW only works in that case if they're aligned in memory - see e.g. the [final point here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/FFTW-Execution-in-Fortran.html), and the related parts in the docs as to why that's hard to guarantee.

The two suggestions I've seen in the docs or elsewhere are either

1. Create temporary arrays, construct the plan for those temporary arrays, and copy data into and out of the temporaries before/after the call to execute_dft. I have used this to avoid similar errors in the past, but it's not the best for performance. However, it is a straightforward change that makes it easy to check if this is the cause of the problem.
2. Create multiple plans.

Also, it looks like you're using the [legacy Fortran interface](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Calling-FFTW-from-Legacy-Fortran.html#Calling-FFTW-from-Legacy-Fortran). If possible it's better to use the ["Modern" interface](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Calling-FFTW-from-Modern-Fortran.html#Calling-FFTW-from-Modern-Fortran), but my experience in the past has been that some compilers don't play nicely with that.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and they did not work. It was my understanding that you could create a plan once and use it over and over again if you are using it on the arrays of exactly the size for which you created the plan. Moreover if it was a plan issue, it would give an error no matter what. The crazy thing is that it works fine if the et & bx lines are commented and stops working at an earlier step (first execution of the plan) as soon as I uncomment those lines.

Comment: That's odd. An example file where I've used it in the past would be [this file on github](https://github.com/IanHawke/MultiFluid1d/blob/master/compute_fft_mod.F90), but I can't see anything obvious that isn't in the suggestion. If it is FFTW stomping all over the memory, the commented out lines in your code are where I would expect it to fail.